# Colocar numeração sobre as curvas do gráfico (matplotlib)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Tenho um código em Python para a simulação de um modelo matemático que estou estudando. Para gerar os gráficos, estou utilizando apenas a função `plot()` do matplotlib, dentro de um `for` (são diversas curvas numa mesma figura). Não convém colocar o código inteiro aqui, mas a estrutura é basicamente essa:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
L=[10,20,30]
fig1=plt.figure()

for l in L:
    plt.plot(T,T+2*l, label='size= '+str(l))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

A questão é: preciso colocar sobre cada curva, a numeração referente aos dados testados, de forma similar à imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem algum argumento na função `plot()` que eu possa adicionar, ou algum outro método que eu possa usar para fazer isso?
E também na legenda, ao invés de mostrar a linha com cor, mostrar o número.

Obs: Eu sei que eu posso fazer cada curva de uma cor,espessura ou desenho diferente, porém (infelizmente) para esse trabalho preciso que o gráfico tenha este formato específico, com a legenda sendo indicada pela numeração, e não por cores, por exemplo.

---

### EDIT (problema resolvido)

Baseado no que o @darcamo fez, consegui colocar as numerações na curva.

Baseado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123127/how-do-you-just-show-the-text-label-in-plot-legend-e-g-remove-a-labels-line) consegui ocultar os handles e deixar as legendas da forma que eu queria.

O código final ficou assim:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.linspace(0, 100, 2000)
L=[10,20,30]
fig1=plt.figure()
for n, l in enumerate(L):
    y=T+2*l
    label=str(n+1)+' => Size = '+str(l)
    plt.plot(T,y,label=label)
    y_shift=0.05*y[-1]
    plt.text(T[-200], y[-200]+y_shift, str(n+1))

leg = plt.legend(handlelength=0, handletextpad=0, fancybox=True)
for item in leg.legendHandles:
    item.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Gerando o seguinte gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `plt.text` para colocar um texto em um local específico.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
L=[10,20,30]


fig1=plt.figure()

for l in L:
    y = T+2*l
    plt.plot(T, y, label='size= '+str(l))
    y_shift = 5  # Um deslocamento pra cima para o texto ficar acima da curva
    plt.text(T[500], y[500] + y_shift, str(l))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Quanto a legenda, se todas as curvas vão ser iguais você realmente precisa da legenda? Afinal já vai ter um texto próximo a cada curva indicando qual é a numeração da curva.

[image: curvas com numeração]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou tentar assim que possível. Mas então, as curvas não são iguais, são parecidas com as da imagem que eu coloquei. Esse código só foi pra exemplificar a estrutura que eu tava usando, não faria sentido eu colocar as equações reais que eu tô usando, pois ficaria enorme e não agregaria nada ao problema. Eu preciso da legenda sim, pois terei por exemplo, as curvas 1, 2 e 3, cada uma é reflexo de uma informação diferente, e como eu disse, eu poderia fazer isso de outras formas mais simples, mas para o trabalho que estou fazendo, preciso desse formato específico da imagem.

Comment: Me referi iguais quanto ao estilo. Quando o estilo diferencia as curvas, como com cores diferentes, você precisa da legenda para dizer o que o estilo significa (a curva vermelha corresponde a esse caso, a amarela aquele outro, etc.). Se todas tem o mesmo estilo e você estiver adicionando um número em cada curva esse número já é, de certa forma, uma legenda.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi o que você quis dizer. Mas a legenda seria como a da imagem, por exemplo 1 -> Size=100um... . Ao invés do estilo da linha, seria a numeração na legenda.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda!